# setInterval() is not wotking in azure microsoft

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, google-api-nodejs-client

setInterval() is not working in Azure Microsoft. I need a function to do the task every month or week? so what can I do? the code is working without azure but with azure not working?

> nodejs code :

```
setInterval(async function check() {
  if ((date.getDate() == 8) && (date.getHours() == 18) && (date.getMinutes() == 39) && (date.getSeconds() == 00)) {
  await Drawings.find({}).then((data) => {
    data.sort(function (a, b) {
      return b.stars - a.stars;
    })
    if (data == null) {
      return;
    }
    AllDrawings.updateMany({
      "potmCurrentWinner": true
    }, {
      $set: {
        "potmCurrentWinner": false
      }
    }, async function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return;
      }
      // move the drawing to potm
      await AllDrawings.updateOne({
        "DrawingName": data[0]['DrawingName']
      }, {
        $set: {
          "potmCurrentWinner": true,
          "potm": true
        }
      }, async function (err) {
        //move file
        await User.updateOne({
          userName: data[0].Drawer
        }, {
          $inc: {
            stars: 25
          }
        })
        console.log("done3");

        await User.updateOne({
          userName: data[0].Drawer
        }, {
          $inc: {
            drawingOfTheMonth: 1
          }
        });
        //delete all drawwing the u give star
        await User.updateMany({}, {
          $set: {
            drawingThatGotYourStar: []
          }
        });
        await Drawings.deleteMany({});
        console.log("done4");
      });
    });
})
```

Comment: Dude, this is crazy, your running this every 1ms.
Think about a better way of doing it.
Like, setTimeout to setTimout that get current date and check how much time is the next time you want it to run.

Comment: it didnt work too

Comment: try using a cronjob

Comment: @AhmedKhalid What do you mean by "not working in Azure"? 
how did you deploy your code?

Answer (score 0):

you have missing code here, the brackets from the initial condition and the closing parenthesis for the setInterval function call

Comment: yes i know i forget to copy all the code but it is not working in azure it works without azure